# How did "realize" change from "make real" to 2 new senses: 'understand', 'come to understand'?

Tags: etymology

Millar concedes that "It is not at all obvious how this change could have occurred", and he's a historical linguistics professor! Alas he doesn't expatiate it. Can someone please expound this semantic shift then?

> It is not always easy to understand why a word changes its meaning. The word *realize*
> formerly meant ‘make real’, and still sometimes does, as in *She finally realized her childhood
> ambition*. But the word has acquired two new senses: ‘understand’, as in *I realize
> that time is short*, and ‘come to understand’, as in *She suddenly realized that she had
> forgotten her keys*. **It is not at all obvious how this change could have occurred [Embolding mine]**, since the
> new senses actually require a different construction (a *that*-complement clause) from the
> old sense (a simple transitive construction). The change in meaning has been so dramatic
> that few people are now aware that *realize* is related to *real*.

Revised by Robert McColl Millar, *Trask's Historical Linguistics* [(2015 3e)](https://www.routledge.com/Trasks-Historical-Linguistics/Millar-Trask/p/book/9780415706582), pp 8-9. [Trask died in 2004.](https://www.theguardian.com/news/2004/apr/08/guardianobituaries1)

Comment: What is expatiate? [expound on]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Selecting some of the OED's definitions in chronological order, I see a three step process (my numbering):

1. *To give real existence to something.*
2. *To present as real to the mind; to make to seem real; to bring vividly or clearly to mind as if real*
3. *To conceive of as being real; to apprehend with the clearness or detail of reality; (in later use also) to become aware of or come to understand (a fact, situation, etc.).*

In other words, the original meaning is to intentionally bring into reality;
the second is to *intentionally* imagine that this were so; and, finally, to come to mind *unintentionally*

> I realized (made real) A.
> I (intentionally) realized (made real in my mind) A. =  to "build" a picture.
> I  (unintentionally) realized/came to realize (that) A.

In the end, A is no longer one thing, but an idea/concept requiring a clause. A clause is required because what we are *realizing* becomes more complex, for example an entire situation, as the OED definition states in (3) above, which sums up this transformation in meaning. *Meaning (2) is the fulcrum, making the process a mental one.*

The *that* clause also nicely serves to distinguish (a) from (b) and (c):

(a) *I realized my dream*

(b) *I woke up and realized it was a dream*
(c) *I realized it was a pipe dream.*

It would be interesting to see whether we really can sharply divide *all* usages into (b) *suddenly realize* and (c) *come to realize*. We can usually tell from the context/timespan, but I think there are instances that blur the line, as, perhaps, in the following examples I've found.

---

> It was easy to pick on poor, weak homeless people. I was trying to be
> as normal as possible, but for the police I was homeless. That's when
> I **first realized** I was one of “them” in their eyes. [S. C.
> Greenfield; *Sacred Shelter: 13 Journeys of Homelessness and
> healing*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sacred_Shelter/hIuUDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22When%20I%20first%20realized%22&pg=PT240&printsec=frontcover)

> I don't remember exactly how or when I **first realized** I could sing
> like Elvis—maybe in the shower, maybe in the car, I don't know...
> [Matthew Vollbrecht; *Blind Faith*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Blind_Faith/5sUFlfBlvUYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22When%20I%20first%20realized%22&pg=PA171&printsec=frontcover)

I think the adjective *first* in these examples refers to the *beginning* of a gradual *coming to realize* process but also, perhaps, the first a series of discrete "realization events," which may each be more or less sudden, but, one would think, gradually less surprising.

> "Where are we?" he asked.
> The man didn't respond. Dawkins blinked,
> looked left and right, and **slowly realized** he was in a small jet
> that was airborne and probably had been for a while. [D. Mann and R. Pezzulo; *SEAL
> Team Six: Hunt the Dragon*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/SEAL_Team_Six_Hunt_the_Dragon/_42DCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Slowly%20realized%20she%20left&pg=PT73&printsec=frontcover)

Here IMO the *slowly* puts us in a no-man's-land (no-person's-land ?) between the *eventive* and *stative* senses as E.A. refers to them in his comment below.  Would there be much difference if the time period were shorter by seconds or minutes (*...and suddenly realized...*), aside from clearly pushing the meaning to the eventive?

Comment: The deductions look very plausible, but isn't 'suddenly realise' = 'come to realise', eventive, whereas 'I realise that time is short' uses the stative sense?

Comment: I agree (and was acknowledging) that there are two meanings, and *suddenly realize* would make one clear. However, I'm not sure that *slowly realize* can't be used for both. But for both meanings we're in the "unintentional" realm. To me, that's the big leap.

Comment: I'd use 'slowly come to realise' for the gradual process of becoming convinced or fully cognisant.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Examples added. Thank you